# Custom Record Delimiter for HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

For Hive version - 0.14
Can we provide a custom record delimiter "\r\r\n" instead of defaults ' `[ "\r" , "\n", "\r\n" ]`

As a result, in my case 2 lines become 4 lines in HIVE because of default line separators whereas I needed "\r\r\n" to be line separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there is custom field delimiter org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader , for custom record delimiter converted newlines to null using PIG and used newline as record delimiter